# How do I connect to my local SQL instance in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, configuration

I've installed VS2010 Express and all associated SQL. I've got an instance running on my local machines of `.\sqlexpress` and I can connect to it with SSMS. I've created some tables etc.

I want to use Linq to SQL so I have created a new empty `.dbml` file in my solution. I assume the next step is to connect to the database, but I don't know how as I've never done this before.

I tried *Add Connection* as it suggests, and the Data Source I can choose Access Database, SQL Server Compact 3.5 or SQL Server Database File.

The Database File one says, "use it to connect to a local instance", so I click that. Then it asks for a database file name, new or existing. Surely I should be typing in the instance name not doing this file thing? If I do type something in, it crease a .mdf in my documents folder and it doesn't really help me much.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out via a blog post or two somewhere online. With the express edition, the option to connect to a local database in the normal way via IP or ./sqlexpress is not present. You have to connect using a File, by finding the .mdf file on your hard disk (within the SQL server folder somewhere) that represents your database, and selecting it.

I have no idea what happens if you update your database schema in SSMS, or why they've restricted it to this bizarre method, but it works and I have been able to query my database.

Answer (score 0):

it's easier than you think.

1. you create a new database in SQL Management Studio, you call it
   whatever, `myDatabase`...
2. from Visual Studio you select the SQL Provider and you select the
   local instance and the `myDatabase` as db name.

everything is basically as you said except that you should have created a database and you should then select it in VS.

doing this from a new EF model, VS will store the connection string compatible with EF format in the app.config so you will be able to check it and see how such connection string is written.

Comment: I think the problem might be in my data source list, I don't think Database File is the right one because there is no way to connect and browse available database as I would expect. The only data provider I have is .NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server compact 3.5